# search for brackets and add \ to it in gvim

Tags: regex, vim

I am new to Vim. Please help to search and add `\` to the string.

For example, for `[1][sometest & numbers][7]`, the output should be
`[1]\[sometest & numbers\][7]`.

I could change the open bracket, `[`, with this

```
:%s/\[[a-z]\&\[/\\\[/g
```

but couldn't do it for `]` (close bracket).

Comment: output should be [1]\\[sometest & numbers\\][7].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match any `]` or `[` that are not part of a `[<DIGITS_HERE>]` substring, you may use

```
:%s/\v\[(\d+])@!|(\[\d+)@<!]/\\&/g
```

Here,

- `\v` - truns on very magic mode
- `\[(\d+])@!` - a `[` char not followed with 1+ digits and then `]`
- `|` - or
- `(\[\d+)@<!]` - a `]` char not immediately preceded with `[` and 1+ digits
- `/\\&` - replacing the matches with `\` and the found match
- `/g` - globally.

Comment: thanks for the replay, only problem is the middle string contains numbers also.
Means [1][hello12hi[7] like this, from your suggestion it wont add \ to this string.

Comment: @swarak Try another solution: it just makes sure the `[` or `]` matched are not part of a `[<DIGITS>]` substring.

Comment: Thanks you very very much sir, its working, you have no idea how long I am suffering to figure this out, almost trying from one day. I had a file with thousands of lines, and with this in few sec job done. thanks once again sir. and where can I learn this regex and gvim more ? can you provide  book or links  suggestions please ?

Comment: @swarak [This Vim regex documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html) is quite good. There are other nice resources, like https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind

Answer (score 0):

Well the basic idea here is to split the string up into parts:

```
[1][sometest & numbers][7]
```

can be split into:

1. `[1]`
2. `[`
3. `sometest & numbers`
4. `]`
5. `[7]`

Then you build your string back with part 1 + `\[` + part 3 + `\]` + part 5.

This can be done with capturing groups. have a look at [`:h \(`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%28).
This should point you in the right direction. Have fun!